# Create a query between two timestamps in feathersjs

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs

How do I create a query in feathersjs where I can find all the rows between two timestamps. I am using mysql as the database.

This is what I have so far:

```
const moment = require("moment");

...

app
.service("bids")
.find({
  query: {
    rate: "official",
    $and: [
      {
        updatedAt: { $gt: moment().subtract(1, "days").startOf("day") },
        updatedAt: { $lt: moment().subtract(1, "days").endOf("day") },
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

I'd like to find everything between yesterday's 24hours. I have also tried the `$or` syntax.
Somebody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply multiple operators to the same condition:

```
app
.service("bids")
.find({
  query: {
    rate: "official",
    updatedAt: {
      $gt: moment().subtract(1, "days").startOf("day"),
      $lt: moment().subtract(1, "days").endOf("day")
    }
  },
})
```